# Unable to run tests with pytest-bdd 4.1.0 and python 3.7.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I was using python 3.4.4 and pytes-bdd 3.1.0 and I was able to execute test cases with the below command

```
pytest-bdd -sv test_tc.py
```

but since I have started using python 3.7.5 and pytest-bdd 4.1.0 then if I use above command, I am getting the below error

```
pytest-bdd: error: argument command: invalid choice: test_tc.py (choose from ;migrate', 'generate')
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are mixing the usage of the command `pytest` and the command `pytest-bdd` as the arguments `-sv test_tx.py` is meant for `pytest`. Try this instead:

```
pytest -sv test_tc.py
```

Based on the [docs](https://pytest-bdd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#test-code-generation-helpers) and also on the `--help` of `pytest-bdd`, it only accepts either `migrate` or `generate`:

```
pytest-bdd generate features/some.feature > tests/functional/test_some.py
```